# Using @ngrx/store element in Angular AuthGuard

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-store, auth-guard

I am trying to use a element from ngrx/store in my authguardService.
When the routing comes to the point where it checks canActivate it works correctly, but when the element changes, the route guard doesn't change it's output and the canActivate function still returns through even though it should return false.

Code for the canActivate function:

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return this.store.pipe(
      select('account'),
      map((account) => {
        console.log('account', account);
        if (account.agb === true) {
          return true;
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/agb']);
          return false;
        }
      }),
      take(1)
    );
  }
```

Routing:

```
{
        path: '',
        canActivate: [BesucherGuardService],
        children: [
          { 
            path: 'offers',
            component: BesucherTestComponent
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService, AgbGuardService, LernenderGuardService],
        children: [
          {
            path: 'offers',
            component: LernenderTestComponent
          }
        ]
      },
```

As you can see in the code above I have the route /offers defined two times, one for when you are a Besucher and one for when you are a Lernender
Unfortunatly even after account.role has changed to LERNENDER in the store it still matches the route because the BesucherGuardService seems to not be aware of the change of the account.role variable.

How can I fix this?

Comment: When you use `take(1)` in your observable pipe, it kills the subscription after the first emitted value.

Comment: Well basicly that is what I want, isn't it?
CanActivate is supposed to be activated everytime the AuthGuard action is met in the routing file, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: That means that `canActivate()` will only ever return once, total. Not per call...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.
What do yo ufigure would be the right form of writting the canActivate function then?

Comment: Try simply removing the `take(1)` operator from you observable pipe.

Comment: Unfortunatly, that doesn't work

Comment: I don't think it's problem with take(1). I have couple of questions: 1) is the top code that you've passed from BesucherGuardService? Or some other file? 2) Am I correct that you want to access `/offers` route, and `if (account.agb === true)` then you want to access BesucherTestComponent, and if not, then LernenderTestComponent? If I'm correct - what is current problem? Does `this.store.pipe(select('account')` not change?

Comment: I fixed the problem by using a Variable of Type account from my session service. I subcribed to account from the store, and when ever it changes i reasign the values in sessionService.account. This made it work for me